# Where can I find a canonical list of sources for worldwide digital GA VFR maps?

Tags: general-aviation, visual-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts

> **Related question:** [Where can I find GA VFR maps for Australia?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/2538/2143)

For various areas of the world, where are authoritative General Aviation VFR maps, charts, and so on available on the web?

Answer (score 1):

*This answer is a Community Wiki. Please edit as appropriate.*

**Australia**

- [OzRunways.com](http://ozrunways.com/)

**United States**

- [VFR Charts](http://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/productcatalog/VFRCharts/) from the U.S. Federal Aviation Administration

Answer (score -2):

The short answer is the most of the world is not covered very well, not even on paper charts.  Operational Navigation Charts (ONC) are available for most of the world, but they're not approved for navigation.  That said, if there's nothing else available, an ONC chart plus GPS can still be useful.