# Where can I get IFR charts for throughout the world?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, navigation, aeronautical-charts, ifr-navigation

(Note [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/11853/canonical-list-of-sources-for-worldwide-digital-ga-vfr-maps) asks about VFR charts.)

In the U.S, I can get IFR navigation charts from [Aeronav](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/ifr/) or [Jeppesen](http://ww1.jeppesen.com/personal-solutions/aviation/ifr-charts.jsp).

Do IFR charts exist worldwide? If so, where can I go for charts of other countries? (A list would be nice since there probably isn't one canonical source?). If not, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 6):

The primary source for every country would be the countries' [Aeronautical Information Publication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeronautical_Information_Publication) (AIP). In some cases the AIP is freely accessible, printed copies can be directly obtained from the [Civil Aviation Authority](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_Aviation_Authority) (CAA) or commercial companies authorized to distribute these, such as Jeppesen.

In some cases there will be a joint resource for certain areas, e.g.
The IFR charts for European countries can be obtained as digital copies from [EAD EUROCONTROL](http://ead-website.ead-it.com/publicuser/public/pu/login.do).

Comment: https://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/ais-online This link is a good source for finding AIS information for almost the entire world

Answer (score 2):

Not sure whether you want them just for informational purposes or for actual flight planning.

https://skyvector.com/ has IFR and VFR charts (and airport information) for the entire planet. I don't know how current they are and whether they are legal for use as operational charts for aircraft operations, but for informational and simulation purposes they're certainly good enough.