# Where can I find airport diagrams from airports all over the world?

Tags: aeronautical-charts

I am trying to build a database of airport diagrams (PDF documents). For the US, the FAA seems to be the best source. Are there any other free sources for Europe, Asia, etc...

Also the data needs to be reliable.

Comment: This is likely the same answer than [Where can I get IFR charts for throughout the world?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13463/3201), in the national AIP.

Answer (score 1):

For Europe, the European AIS database ([EAD](https://www.ead.eurocontrol.int/cms-eadbasic/opencms/en/login/ead-basic/)) would be the best source.