# What do European pilots use for IFR enroute charting (besides Jeppesen)?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts, ifr-navigation

Is there something equivalent to FAA IFR enroute charts for European countries, where you can see published routes, holds, minimum altitudes, etc?  I can find terminal area procedures in the AIPs, but the Eurocontrol enroute charts contain hardly any useful information.

Comment: All countries publish relevant information in the national AIP. Some include charts, others mainly publish textual information. It is then up to chart providers (Jeppesen, Lido etc.) to compile the data into relevant charts. It might be easier to answer your question if you specify which exact information you are looking for

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! [This question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/13463/62) is very similar, although I'm not sure it adds much to what you already know.

Comment: @expeditedescent So if I don't want to pay the ridiculous prices for Jepp charts in Europe, what are my options for enroute flight planning?

Comment: All the info you need is published in the national AIPs. Most of which are freely available online

Comment: Thanks, I am just getting used to where everything is in the AIPs (because we don't use them in the US).  I was looking at Eurocontrol, but now it seems obvious I'd find them in the ENR section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Europe, like in most of the world, IFR enroute charts are published in ENR 6 of the national AIP, which can be found notably from [Eurocontrol @IS online](https://www.eurocontrol.int/articles/ais-online). Some countries publish these charts in sections ENR 3.x.

Some countries like Spain even publish [electronic charts](https://insignia.enaire.es/).

More details (route data tables) about IFR routes are published in the following sections:

- ENR 3.1 Lower ATS routes
- ENR 3.2 Upper ATS routes
- ENR 3.3 Area navigation (RNAV) routes
- ENR 3.4 Helicopter routes

Note: this organisation of routes will change soon.

There are numerous companies offering flight manuals beside Jeppesen and Lido: Navblue is one example.